# Exception adding JS function to Angular 2 TS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Our web app is an Angular 2 app developed using TypeScript. The web app will live inside an Android web view as well as inside a web browser. The web app calls a JavaScript function when it is living inside a web view. The following code (from **frmcall.android.js**) registers that function in Angular 2:

```
System.register([], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var callAndorid;
    return {
        setters:[],
        execute: function() {
            callAndorid = (function () {
                function callAndorid() {
                }
                callAndorid.prototype.passParam = function (fldMerchCode, fldMerchRefNbr, fldTxnAmt, fldTxnScAmt, fldDatTimeTxn, fldDate1, fldDate2) {
                    passParameters(fldMerchCode, fldMerchRefNbr, fldTxnAmt, fldTxnScAmt, fldDatTimeTxn, fldDate1, fldDate2);
                };
                return callAndorid;
            }());
            exports_1("callAndorid", callAndorid);
        }
    }
});
```

This is working perfectly in some environments but fails miserably in others. When failure occurs we get this kind of message:

[image]

Is there anyway to avoid this problem?

**Edit: I would like to add code that loads frmcall.android.js**

```
System.register(['angular2/core', 'angular2/router', '../framework/rp-http.service', '../framework/rp-intercom.service', '../framework/rp-bean', '../framework/rp-input.component', '../framework/rp-references', '../util/rp-client.util', 'angular2/http', '../samples/frmcall.android'], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
        var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
        if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
        else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
        return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
    };
    var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
        if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
    };
    var core_1, router_1, rp_http_service_1, rp_intercom_service_1, rp_bean_1, rp_input_component_1, rp_references_1, rp_client_util_1, http_1, frmcall_android_1;
```

Comment: looks like syntax error message

Comment: @AlexeyObukhov yes it does but the code runs if it is on certain servers

Comment: Check in the Chrome devtools network tab if `frmcall.android.js` has the right content. I bet that your app try to load the `index.html` instead.